# Use of the Schwarz inequality in proving the Chung Erdős inequality

Tags: probability, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to understand a proof of the Chung Erdős inequality. All the sources I can find (including related questions and answers on MSE) state something along the following lines: if $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are events and if $X_i$ is the random variable given by the characteristic function of $A_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$, then the following inequality follows from the Schwarz inequality:

$$[E(X_1+...+X_n)]^2 \leq P(X_1+...+X_{n}>0)E[(X_{1}+...+X_n)^2]$$

I am probably being particularly stupid about this, but I just can't see how to apply the Schwarz inequality to get the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is that $E[UV]^2\le E[U^2] E[V^2]$.  (This is the usual C-S inequality applied to the space of real-valued random variables with second moments, with inner product $\langle X,Y\rangle=E[XY]$.)

Apply this in the case $U=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ and $V=I_{U>0}$.  Note that $E[U]=E[UV]$, that $V^2=V$ and that $E[V^2] = E[V] = P(U>0)$, delivering your inequality
$$E[X_1+\cdots+X_n]^2 = E[UV]^2\le E[V^2] E[U^2] = P(X_1+\cdots+X_n>0)E[(X_1+\cdots+X_n)^2].$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ and denote by $f$ its probability density function.

Write $X f = \sqrt{f} (X \sqrt{f})$. Then

$$\left(\int X f dX\right)^2 \leq \int f dX \int X^2 f dX$$

by Cauchy-Schwarz.